# Global name 'student_average' is not defined

Tags: python, function

I am trying to do an exercise on codeacademy with the following error:

"Oops, try again. get_class_average([alice]) resulted in an error: global name 'student_average' is not defined"

for the following code:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    alpha = total/len(numbers)
    return alpha

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student['homework'])
    quizzes = average(student['quizzes'])
    tests = average(student['tests'])
    student_average = homework*10/100 + quizzes*30/100 + tests*60/100
    return student_average

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score < 90 and score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score < 80 and score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score < 70 and score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"        

print get_letter_grade(lloyd)

def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    alpha2 = 0
    for item in students:
        alpha2 = student_average(student)
        results.append(alpha2)
    return alpha2 / len(students)

print get_class_average([lloyd, alice, tyler])
```

Comment: Can you please indent your program correctly. and you seem to be using `student_average` as a function, instead of `get_average()` .

Answer (score 4):

You have a mistaken call to your function `get_average(student)` in your `for` loop. Instead of calling it by `get_average(student)` you used `student_average(student)`.

Since `student_average` *is actually a variable* and *it isn't defined outside your function* `get_average()`, it results in an obvious error since ***it is only visible inside the function it was defined***:

This call:

```
for item in students:
    alpha2 = student_average(student)
```

Should instead be:

```
for item in students:
    alpha2 = get_average(student)
```